# Check that a method throws an exception when applied to any element of a list of values

Tags: java, exception, junit

I want to write unit tests for a parser and would like to check that it correctly throws an exception for all input strings in a list. Now as I understand it, the standard approach with *JUnit* would be to write a separate test method for each case:

```
public final class ParseFailureTest1 {
    @Test(expected = ParseException.class)
    public void testParseFailure1() throws Exception {
        Parser.parse("[1 2]"); // Missing comma
    }

    @Test(expected = ParseException.class)
    public void testParseFailure2() throws Exception {
        Parser.parse("[1, 2,]"); // Additional commas
    }
}
```

But as I want to apply the same test to 20 or 50 different strings, it seems impractical.

An alternative would be to explicitly check for an exception with a `catch` block:

```
public final class ParseFailureTest2 {
    @Test
    public void testParseFailure() throws Exception {
        List<String> documents = Arrays.asList(
            "[1 2]", // Missing comma
            "[1, 2,]"); // Additional commas

        for (String document : documents) {
            try {
                Parser.parse(document);

                throw new AssertionError("Exception was not thrown");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // Expected, do nothing.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is error prone and I won't get any information about which exception was expected and if a different exception was thrown, it would count as a test error and not a failure.

My solution would be to use a method similar to `expectException` below:

```
public final class ParseFailureTest3 {
    @Test
    public void testParseFailure() throws Exception {
        List<String> documents = Arrays.asList(
            "[1 2]", // Missing comma
            "[1, 2,]"); // Additional commas

        for (final String document : documents) {
            expectException(ParseException.class, new TestRunnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Throwable {
                    Parser.parse(document);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void expectException(Class<? extends Throwable> expected, TestRunnable test) {
        try {
            test.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (e.getClass() == expected) {
                return; // Expected, do nothing.
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError(String.format("Wrong exception was thrown: %s instead of %s", e.getClass(), expected), e);
            }
        }

        throw new AssertionError(String.format("Expected exception was not thrown: %s", expected));
    }

    public interface TestRunnable {
        void run() throws Throwable;
    }
}
```

Is there a method for that purpose in the JUnit framework or a related library or would you suggest a different approach (or one of my rejected approaches) to the problem?

Comment: Have you tried parameterized JUnit testing?

Comment: @maheeka That seems to be what I want. Can you write a short example and post it as an answer?

Comment: JUnit parameterized testing is the way to go. You do not need multiple threads or anything as such. JUnit4 can handle it for you. (Refer my answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JUnit4 for Parameterized test feature. The following code should work.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class ParseTest {

    private String parseValue;

    public ParseTest(String parseValue) {
        this.parseValue = parseValue;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "[1 2]" }, { "[1,2,]" } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test(expected = ParseException.class)
    public void testParseFailure1() throws Exception {
        Parse.parse(parseValue);
    }

}
```

For more info refer http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `fail()` method:

```
@Test
public void testParseFailure() throws Exception {
    List<String> documents = Arrays.asList(
        "[1 2]", // Missing comma
        "[1, 2,]"); // Additional commas

    for (String document : documents) {
        try {
            Parser.parse(document);
            fail("Parsing " + document + " should have thrown a ParseException");
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            // Expected, do nothing.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be somekind paranoid, you will also need to catch Exception after catching ParseException, to ensure it wasn't a NPE.

Comment: No. That would be caught by JUnit which would mark the test in error.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the answer but you are missing the point. I don't want to copy-paste that try-catch construct into each test case I where I need to iterate over a list.

Comment: Then your approach is fine except that: 1. it should use fail(), 2. it should not make an equality check on the exception class, but an isInstanceof check, to allow subclasses of ParseException to be thrown. I'm not sure having to make the same exception check for a whole list of inputs is such a frequent requirement, and I'm not sure implementing an anonymous class is really more readable and fast than a simple try/catch block.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with both of your objections. I've checked and `org.junit.Test` accepts subclasses of the declared, expected exception too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, keeping the `fail` idea from the previous answer, for if you care about getting the right message in the exception.

```
public final class ParseFailureTest {
  @Test
  public void testParseFailure() throws Exception {
      Map<String, String> documents = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
      documents.put("[1 2]", "Missing comma");
      documents.put("[1, 2,]", "Additional commas");

      for (Entry<String,String> entry : documents.entrySet()) {
          try {
              Parser.parse(entry.getKey());
              fail("Parsing " + entry.getKey() + 
                      " should have thrown a ParseException");
          } catch (ParseException e) {
              assertEquals(entry.getValue(), e.getMessage());
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this test, because it is testing two things.

Comment: Hmmm. I think of it as "Did the Parser throw the right exception?".

Comment: But that's a different test.